# processing highland stream chunks using async

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js, highland.js

I'm using `highland.js` to process a file using a stream to read the contents between two delimiters. I'm also using `async.js` to run a series of http requests in sequence.

Ideally I would like to pass the output `x` from highland as the first function to the `async` series (chain) so that the HTTP requests get executed for each chunk extracted from the stream.

Is this possible? If so, how can this be achieved?

```
var async = require('async');
var _ = require('highland');


_(fs.createReadStream(files[0], { encoding: 'utf8' }))
        .splitBy('-----BEGIN-----\n')
        .splitBy('\n-----END-----\n')
        .filter(chunk => chunk !== '')
        .each(function (x) {
        }).done(function () {

    async.series([
        function(callback) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('Task 1');
                callback(null, 1);
            }, 300);
        },
        function(callback) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('Task 2');
                callback(null, 2);
            }, 200);
        },
    ], function(error, results) {
        console.log(results);
    });

});;
```

Comment: what is `done` in this case?

Comment: Why is `x` not passed to the function at `javascript` at Question?

Comment: `done` http://highlandjs.org/#done was a hangover from my working code and tells the stream process to finish. I could probable remove it.

Comment: @guest271314 - do you mean create a function and call it in place of x and pass the content to it ?

Comment: _"Ideally I would like to pass the output `x`"_ Pass `x` to `async.series` within `.done()` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the calls to `each` and `done`. After filtering, you can follow it up with `.toArray(callback)`. The callback is passed an array that contains the results from highland. You might refactor like this

```
var Q = require('q');
var _ = require('highland');


_(fs.createReadStream(files[0], { encoding: 'utf8' }))
        .splitBy('-----BEGIN-----\n')
        .splitBy('\n-----END-----\n')
        .filter(chunk => chunk !== '')
        .each(asyncTasks);

function asyncTasks(x) { // here, x will be each of the results from highland
    async.series([
      // do something with x results
        function(callback) {
          console.log('Task 1');
          callback(null, 1);
        },
        // do something else with x results
        function(callback) {
          console.log('Task 2');
          callback(null, 2);
        },
    ], function(error, results) {
        console.log(results);
    });
}
```

[here](http://highlandjs.org/#toArray) is a link to the documentation for `toArray`. `toArray` consumes the stream, just as `done` also does. Let me know if you have any questions.

Although honestly, I think you would be better off using promises instead. Although part of it is just personal preferrence, partly because it makes the code more readable. From [what I've read](http://thanpol.as/javascript/promises-a-performance-hits-you-should-be-aware-of/), async is more performant than promises, but the nice part about promises is that you can pass the results from one function to the next. So in your example, you could do some stuff to `x` in the first part, and then pass your modified result to the next function, and the next function, and so on. Where when you're using `async.series`, you finish each function by calling `callback(null, result)`, and you don't get the results until you finish at the very end of the series when you get all the results from all of the calls to `callback`. Now, you could always save your results to some variable outside of async.series, but that would make your code messier. If you wanted to re-write it with promises, it would look as follows. I am using `q` here, but it is just one of many promise libraries you could use.

```
    var async = require('async');
    var _ = require('highland');


    _(fs.createReadStream(files[0], { encoding: 'utf8' }))
            .splitBy('-----BEGIN-----\n')
            .splitBy('\n-----END-----\n')
            .filter(chunk => chunk !== '')
            .each(asyncTasks);

    function asyncTasks(x) { // here, x will be an array of the results from highland
      return asyncTask1(x)
              .then(asyncTask2)
              .then(asyncTask3)
    }

    function asyncTask1(x) {
      var deferred = Q.defer();

      // do some stuff

      if (// some error condition) {
        deferred.reject();
      } else {
        deferred.resolve(x); // or pass along some modified version of x
      }

      return deferred.promise;
    }

    function asyncTask2(x) {
      // same structure as above
    }

    function asyncTask3(x) {
      // same structure as above
    }
```

Some asynchronous APIs these days have started to return promises, in addition to accepting callback, or sometimes in place of. So it would be a good thing to get comfortable with. Promises are super useful. You can read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference).

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this now. Why is Q better and how would it look using it. I would be happy to switch if its better,

Comment: Looks like x is an array of all of the chunks as oppose to just the chunk that needs to be passed to the async chain.

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry, I misunderstood your need. I updated the code. Just slight change. Now you can call each and then pass in the same function as before. Now asyncTasks will be called on each result from highlands. Each consumes the stream so you don't need need to call `done() as well`.

Comment: Also gave explanation about using promises. It's not a hugely important issue for this particular example, but it might be worth looking into for future use.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Hayden.

Comment: Hmm I have a bit of a strange issue with both async & Q if I use `.each(asyncTasks)` and call the `asyncTasks` function my http `request` run incredibly slow when processing ~17000 chunks from the stream. However, if process the output to create an array of functions, then pass that to async, it runs about 200 times faster.

Comment: I don't think I quite get you, and I think I'm missing some of the context, but if you found a way to make it run better, then that's awesome. Go for that way.